# How I can pack into tar-file only last directory from path?

Tags: linux, command-line, path, archive, tar

How I can pack into tar-file only last directory from path?
For example, I have several paths

```
/usr/local/files/dir1/

   file1.txt
   file2.txt
   file3.txt

/usr/local/files/dir2/

   file3.txt
   file4.txt
   file5.txt
```

if I run command:

```
tar czf my_arch.tar.gz -C /usr/local/files/dir1 .
```

I gain only containment of **dir1** catalog, without itself.

So I have - my_arch.tar.gz/file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, But I need structure like that inside my archive -

```
my_arch.tar.gz/dir1/file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt
```

How I can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
$ tar vczf tmp/export/files.tar.gz -C tmp/export src
```

structure for **files.tar.gz**

```sh
src
src/app
src/app/main.js
src/app/util
src/app/util/runtime.js
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
cd /usr/local/files
tar -cvzf my_arch.tar.gz dir1
```

The -C directive will make you change into dir1 and thus not archive the folder, but its contents:

> ```
>  -C, --directory DIR
>      change to directory DIR
> ```

Comment: It isn't safe to use cd command while you're running big scripts.

Comment: You did not state that you were running a script. 
Why is it "unsafe"? 
The "-C" flag is also causing tar to change into the directory.

If you are worried about non-existing directories you could add error handling `cd /usr/local/files/dir1 || { dostuff; }`

Comment: Also, if you are worried about changing directories in the main thread of your shell, you can use a sub-shell by adding parentheses:  
`(  
cd /usr/local/files  
tar -cvzf my_arch.tar.gz dir1  
)`.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot do this directly through tar.
here's my suggestion :

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir=/my_dir/whit/long_and/complicated_path/the_stuff_is_here
dirname=$(dirname $mydir )
basename=$(basename $mydir )

 tar cvf /tmp/$basename.tar    -C $dirname $basename
```

Comment: You make it way to complex. Why not use expansions for those variables?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you want your tar file to contain the directory.

Try it without the -C flag as in:

```
tar -czf my_arch.tar.gz /usr/local/files/dir1
```

Comment: I forgot - I don't need to save path structure. Except last folder.

Comment: Can you explain the "last folder" bit more clearly? Do you mean you only want to archive the contents of the last folder listed by ls ?

Comment: @AlPacifico I think he means dir1 is last directory, then tar should contains dir1/file1,file2..etc. When untar it should extract dir1 directory and all the files inside.I am looking for same think but couldn't find.

Answer (score -1):

If you specify `-C` then you directory path is `./`. Probably the following works like you want:

```
$ touch asdf/foo/bar/{1,2,3}
$ tree asdf/
asdf/
└── foo
    └── bar
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        └── 3

2 directories, 3 files
$ tar -cv -C asdf/foo/bar/ -f asdf.tar ./
./
./3
./2
./1
$ tar tf asdf.tar
./
./3
./2
./1
```